# How many unoriginal pawn moves can be made in a single game?

Tags: problems, pawns, records, notation, mathematics

Consider an "unoriginal pawn move" to be a pawn move whose notation matches a move already played in the game. For instance, after 1.e4 e5 2.d4 exd4 3.e5, there is one unoriginal pawn move, the e5 played by white. If e5 is played again later, that would be another unoriginal pawn move.

(For clarity, "e5+" would be a different move than "e5").

How many unoriginal pawn moves can be played in a single game (assuming all standard rules, legal moves etc)?

[originally asked as part of [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35460/how-many-times-can-the-same-pawn-move-be-made-in-a-game)]

Comment: In the example, 2.... exd5 should be 2.... exd4.

Comment: Thanks, fixed..

Answer (score 6):

60 unoriginal pawn moves can be made in a game by quadrupling the pawns 4 times. One can use the same capture once in each column of 4. Then you can use the exact same move 1+3+3+3+3 times in each column. And finally in the black columns white can make a move (to row 3) and vice versa Total: 15*4 =60

Here is an example game.

```
[FEN ""]

1. Nc3 Nc6 2. Ne4 Ne5 3. Nf6+ exf6 4. Nf3 Ne7 5. Nd4 Nd5 6. Nc6 Nf3+ 7. exf3 Nc3 8. dxc3 dxc6 9. Bd3 Bd6 10. Bg6 Bg3 11. hxg3 hxg6 12. Be3 Be6 13. Bb6 Bb3 14. axb3 axb6 15. Ra5 Rh4 16. Rc5 Rb4 17. cxb4 bxc5 18. b5 c4 19. c3 b6 20. Rh5 Ra4 21. Rc5 Rb4 22. cxb4 bxc5 23. b6 c3 24. b7 c4 25. b8=Q c5 26. b5 c2 27. b6 c6 28. b4 c1=Q 29. Qf4 c3 30. Qg5 fxg5 31. b7 g4 32. b8=Q c4 33. Qf4 c2 34. Qg5 Qf4 35. gxf4 c1=Q 36. f5 Qf4 37. g3 f6 38. gxf4 fxg5 39. b5 c3 40. b6 c2 41. b7 c1=Q 42. b8=Q Qc5 43. b3 Qd6 44. b4 c5 45. b5 c4 46. b6 c3 47. b7 c2 48. Qa7 c1=Q 49. b8=Q g3 50. f6 g2 51. f5 Qcc7 52. f4 Kd7 53. f7 g1=N 54. f6 g4 55. f8=Q g5 56. f7 g6 57. f5 g3 58. f6 g2 59. f3 g4 60. f4 g3 61. f5 g5 62. Qh8 g4 63. f8=Q Ne2 64. f7 g1=N 65. f6 g2 66. Qfh6 Nh3 67. f8=Q g1=N 68. Qfg8 g3 69. f7 g2 70. f8=Q Nc3 71. Qe2 Ngxe2 72. Qaa8 g1=N
```